# ModuleFederationPlugin's remote property syntax

Tags: webpack-module-federation

What does this `ui: "ui@http://some.external.host/remoteEntry.js"` syntax mean in ModuleFederationPlugin's `remotes` property.
I understand that ui item is being loaded from an external host, but what does `ui@` before host definition mean ?

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "myApp",
      filename: "myAppEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        ui: "ui@http://some.external.host/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: {
        ...,
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can break this line of the config `ui: "ui@http://some.external.host/remoteEntry.js"`  into three parts: `LocalModuleName: "RemoteModuleName@Host"`. Let's assume `myApp` and `ui` have the following webpack configs for module federation:

```js
// Config for myApp
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "myApp",
  filename: "myAppEntry.js",
  remotes: {
    ui: "ui@http://some.external.host/remoteEntry.js",
  },
  shared: {...},
}),

// Config for ui
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "ui",
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
  exposes: {
    "./Button": "./src/Button",
  },
  shared: {...},
}),
```

**LocalModuleName** is the name under which you can import exposed features from the remote app in the local code, e.g.:

```js
const RemoteButton = React.lazy(() => import("ui/Button"));
```

But you could also change the name to `remoteUI: "ui@http://some.external.host/remoteEntry.js"` and the import would have to look like this:

```js
const RemoteButton = React.lazy(() => import("remoteUI/Button"));
```

This could be useful if two different remotes used the same name in their config.

**RemoteModuleName** refers to the name used in the remote configuration. This is necessary, so `ModuleFederation` can properly initialize the modules.

**Host** is the URL under which you find the remote container script.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Great answer. Kind of crazy this is detailed absolutely nowhere in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/).